# how to change btn background when click /HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a button like read more and when I press it, a text opens downwards. When the text opens, the background of the button will change and when I press the button again to close the text (such as read less), the background of the button will return to its original state.How to do that

```js
function myFunction() {
        var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
        var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
        var btnText = document.getElementsByClassName("skillBtn");
      
        if (dots.style.display === "none") {
          dots.style.display = "inline";
          btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
          moreText.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          dots.style.display = "none";
          btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
          moreText.style.display = "inline";
        }
      }
```

```css
#more {display: none;}
```

```html
<div align="center"><h1 id="skillsid" style="margin-top:10px ;"> Codding dilleri <span id="dots"></span> </h1><span id="more">
    something is written here
    
    <div align="center"><a href="#skillsid"><button class="skillBtn" onclick="myFunction()" ></button></a></div>
```

Comment: an `a` tag cannot contain a `button` tag (and vice versa).

Comment: *"but I need to get the answer to the question I'm looking for, not how to use the a tag correctly..."* and that's why I posted a comment not an answer. Regardless of whether you have found an answer or not, I strongly recommend learning `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript`. [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US) would be a great place for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called **accordion**. There is no reason to write this with JS as HTML has `<details>` and `<summary>` for that:

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Codding dilleri</summary>
  something is written here
</details>
```

IF you want to change styles on a button click then you should `toggle` CSS-classes as below:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let more = document.querySelector('.more');
  more.classList.toggle('d-block');
  button.classList.toggle('bg-red');
  button.textContent = (button.textContent === 'Read More') ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More';
})
```

```css
.more { 
  display: none; 
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <h1 id="skillsid" style="margin-top:10px ;">Codding  dilleri</h1>
  <div class="more">
    something is written here
  </div>
  <button class="skillBtn">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.I will try it but i asked for how to change button background

Comment: And i saw it on the W3school.That's why I used js

Comment: That's why I (along with other seniors) can't recommend w3school. Many topics are outdated or of poor coding quality (HTML, CSS, JS). IT is hard to know as a beginner which tutorial can be used and which should be avoided.